# issue with as.formula() or formula() in lmer within "by" of data.table

Tags: r, data.table, data-analysis, lme4

Specifically, when I pass a model (as a string) in lmer via as.formula() or formula() within the data.table code using the "by", it seems the entire data is being analyzed instead of stratified analysis by the "sim" variable. Sample Code below explains the issue I am facing.

**Step1.** I created a mock data as follows. The data below is not really longitudinal, but should suffice for the purposes of a demo of the issue I am facing.

```
library(data.table)
library(lme4)

# ----  Step1. multiple simulated data ----
Nsim=2
n=20
csize=4

set.seed(10)
y <- round(rnorm(Nsim*n*csize, 0, 3),2)
time <- rep(0:(csize-1),Nsim*n) 
w <- rbinom(Nsim*n,size=1,prob=0.6); w<- rep(w, each=csize)
x<- round(2*runif(Nsim*n*csize)+1,2)

id = rep(rep(1:n,each=csize),Nsim)
sim=rep(1:Nsim,each=n*csize)

dat<- data.table(y, time, w, x, id, sim)
setkey(dat,sim)
# ----  End of (multiple simulated data) ----
```

[Output from Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myWbX.png)

**Step 2.** Forcefully running lmer model for each *sim* to see what the true results should look like.

```
cat('# -----------  Step 2. output we should expect  -----------\n') 
BIC(lmer(y~time+w+x+(1+time|id), data=dat[sim==1,]))
BIC(lmer(y~time+w+x+(1+time|id), data=dat[sim==2,]))
```

[Output from Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVTyt.png)

**Step 3.** Getting the above results using stratified analysis through *by* of *data.table*. Results from ***Step 2*** and ***Step 3*** should be the same and they are.

```
cat('# ------  Step 3. Stratified results using "by" of data.table ------\n')
dat[,BIC(lmer(y~time+w+x+(1+time|id))), by=sim]
```

[Output from Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldXbl.png)

**Step 4.**  Running the stratified analysis by passing string-model in *lmer* through *as.formula()* or *formula()*. This code analyzes the whole data instead of stratified analysis by *sim* (see the results from ***Step 5***)

```
cat('# -----  Step 4. trying "as.formula()" or "formula()" in data.table  -----\n')
dat[,{
   use.form<- as.formula('y~time+w+x+(1+time|id)')
   BIC(lmer(use.form))
   }, by=sim]
```

[Output from Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMgPK.png)

**Step 5.** I confirmed results from *Step 4* are indeed incorrect since it ignores stratification by *sim*, as shown below.

```
cat('# ---------- Step 5.  output NOT expected ------------------\n')
BIC(lmer(y~time+w+x+(1+time|id), data=dat)),'\n')
```

[Output from Step 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOfn6.png)

My code in ***Step 4*** is definitely missing an important aspect of data.table and its *by* process. Any guidance from the community will be much appreciated.

Also, this is my first ever post here. Apologies if I missed something in terms of creating a good post.

Comment: Passing `.SD` to the data argument of the model fixes the issue.  `dat[, BIC(lmer('y~time+w+x+(1+time|id)', .SD)), by=sim]`.  Will leave it to someone more knowledgeable to explain why.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thanks for the prompt response! That definitely addressed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RichieSacramento points out that this is fixed by passing the data explicitly:

> Passing `.SD` to the `data` argument of the model fixes the issue. `dat[, BIC(lmer('y~time+w+x+(1+time|id)', .SD)), by=sim]`.

I can't say **exactly** what's going on without spending a lot more time digging, but evaluation of formulas in `lme4` is rather delicate when the `data` argument isn't specified — `lmer` tries to look in the environment of the formula, but scoping can get complicated/confusing. It's always safest to specify `data` explicitly to avoid these headaches.

Comment: Thanks Ben Bolker!